# how to use a mutation inside a component template? VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm learning Vue with VUEX and I'm making and small app.
That small app call a json data and print it in a template.
I created a mutation called year(), that mutation get a world of a string and return the result but when I use that mutation inside template {{ year(item.fechaInicio) }} return a empty value.

[image: show page]

That's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vue</title>


    <!-- bootstrap 4 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- fontawesome css -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Tipografía -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i|Roboto+Mono:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Jquery -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- cookies jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Vue -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- Vuex -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS estilos -->
    <link href="calendario-2020.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>


    <div class="Calendario" id="caja-vue">
        <p class="calendario-titulo">Calendario Académico</p>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
           <li class="nav-item"><a aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab">Estudiantes</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--TAB 1 ESTUDIANTES-->
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
           <div aria-labelledby="home-tab" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
              <!--Semestres-->
              <div class="flex-container">
                 <div class="Semestre">
                    <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox"><input class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" type="checkbox" /> <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Semestre <span class="num">1</span></label></div>
                    <p>Enero 17-2020<br />
                       Mayo 15-2020
                    </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="Semestre">
                    <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox"><input class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2" type="checkbox" /> <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Semestre <span class="num">2</span></label></div>
                    <p>Agosto 15-2020<br />
                       Diciembre 20-2020
                    </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="Semestre">
                    <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox"><input class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck3" type="checkbox" /> <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3">Intersemestral</label></div>
                    <p>Enero 17-2020<br />
                       Mayo 15-2020
                    </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12 fechas">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-lg-9">&nbsp;</div>
                       <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Organizar por:</option>
                                <option>Fecha Inicio</option>
                                <option>Fecha Final</option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!--Formulario de Busqueda-->
              <div class="Formulario_calndario">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                       <div class="form Formulario_busqueda">
                          <div class="input-group espacio">
                             <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                   <i class="fas fa-search">
                                      <!--icono-->
                                   </i>
                                </button>
                             </div>
                             <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="¿Qué estás buscando?" type="text" />
                          </div>
                          &nbsp;
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Tipo de programa</option>
                                <option>Pregrado</option>
                                <option>Posgrado</option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Categoria</option>
                                <option>Cierre académico</option>
                                <option>Comité de idiomas</option>
                                <option>Exámenes finales</option>
                                <option>Homologaciones, reconocimientos y validaciones</option>
                                <option>Inicio y finalización de clases</option>
                                <option>Otras actividades de la vida universitaria</option>
                                <option>Pago de matrículas</option>
                                <option>Proceso de inducción</option>
                                <option>Publicación de grupos cancelados</option>
                                <option>Recesos y vacaciones</option>
                                <option>Registro de asignaturas</option>
                                <option>Reporte de notas</option>
                                <option>Reserva de cupo, re activaciones de cupo y reintegros</option>
                                <option>Retiro de asignaturas</option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Tipo de programa</option>
                                <option>Escuela de Administración</option>
                                <option>Escuela de Medicina y Ciencias de la Salud</option>
                                <option>Escuela de Ciencias Humanas</option>
                                <option>Facultad de Economía</option>
                                <option>Facultad de Jurisprudencia</option>
                                <option>Facultad de Estudios Internacionales, Políticos y Urbanos</option>
                                <option>Facultad de Ciencias Naturales</option>
                                <option>Facultad de Creación</option>
                                <option>Escuela de Ingeniería, Ciencia y Tecnologí</option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                      <i class="fas fa-search">
                                         <!--icono-->
                                      </i>
                                   </button>
                                </div>
                                <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Programa" type="text" />
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <p><a aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" class="Fecha" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button">Seleccione un mes</a></p>
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                   <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                                      <div class="card card-body"><input class="form-control" id="example-date-input" type="date" value="2011-08-19" /></div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <p><a aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" class="Fecha" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample2" role="button">Seleccione un mes</a></p>
                                <div class="row">
                                   <div class="col">
                                      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
                                         <div class="card card-body">
                                            <p>Fecha inicial</p>
                                            <input class="form-control" id="example-date-input" type="date" value="2011-08-19" />
                                            <p>Fecha final</p>
                                            <input class="form-control" id="example-date-input" type="date" value="2011-08-19" />
                                         </div>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buscar</input>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <input class="btn btn-primary Limpiar" type="submit">Limpiar</input>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    
                        <actividades></actividades>
                    
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <script src="codigo.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

That's my javascript code:

```
//componentes
Vue.component('actividades', {
    template: /*html*/
        ` 
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <template v-for="item of actividades">
                <div class="row Programa-especifico">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 Fecha">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <i class="far fa-calendar">
                                    <!--icono-->
                                </i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 px-5"><strong class="titulo">Marzo 08</strong> <span>Abril 17 2020</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-3 txt">
                            <strong>Tipo de programa</strong> <span>{{ item.tipoPrograma }}</span><br />
                            <strong>Facultad</strong> <span>{{ item.facultad }}</span><br />
                            <strong>Programa</strong> <span>{{ item.programa }}</span><br />
                            <strong>Categoria</strong> <span>{{ item.categoria }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 Descripcion">
                        <p class="titulo">{{ item.contenido }}</p>
                        <!--
                        <p class="txt">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;, making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
                        -->
                        <!--
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt">
                            
                        </i>
                        -->
                        <!--
                        <strong>Lugar:</strong> <span class="txt">Universidad del Rosario, Sede, Claustro, Aula Mutis</span><br />
                        <i class="far fa-calendar">
                            
                        </i>
                        -->
                        <strong>Fecha de inicio:</strong> <span class="txt">
                        Marzo, de {{ year(item.fechaInicio) }}
                        </span><br />
                        <strong>Fecha de cierre:</strong> <span class="txt">12 Marzo, de 2020</span><br />
                        <!--
                        <i class="far fa-clock">
                           
                        </i>
                
                        <strong>Hora:</strong> <span class="txt">De 8:00 a.m. a 12:30 p.m</span>
                        -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 Semestre_uno"><a href="">{{ item.periodo }}</a></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 Cerrado"><a href="">Cerrado</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
        `,
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['actividades','programas']),
    },
    methods: {
        ...Vuex.mapActions(['llamarJson']),
        ...Vuex.mapMutations(['year'])
    }
});

//VueEx
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        actividades: [],
        programas: []
    },
    mutations: {
        llamarJsonMutation(state, llamarJsonAction){
            state.actividades = llamarJsonAction.Nueva_estructura_proveedor;
            state.programas = llamarJsonAction.BD_programas;
        },
        year(date){
            return String(date).substr(8, 2);
        }
    },
    actions: {
        llamarJson: async function({ commit }){
            const data = await fetch('calendario-2021-prueba.json');
            const dataJson = await data.json();
            commit('llamarJsonMutation', dataJson);
        }
    }
});

//Vue
new Vue({
    el: '#caja-vue',
    store: store,
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('llamarJson');
      }
});
```

Comment: You mutation should not return any data, it mutate data in the store and your getters are suppose to retreive that data. So your mutation should define, or modify, a value from your store, and then you create a getters that will retreive the data in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Do not return the value in mutation. Mutations are for mutating states in vuex. Instead, add a property to state as year then in the mutaitioner just add :

```
state.year = String(date).substr(8, 2);
```

Then in your component and in computed add:

```
year(){
    return this.store.state.year;
}
```

And now, you can access `{{year}}` in your template.